# How to display only Permissions and file names using ls command?

Tags: linux, ls

How can I display only Permissions and file names using ls command and how to list all files in a directory including full path, owner, group and permissions for each file?

Answer (score 10):

you can use GNU `find` command instead of `ls` unless you are doing homework

```
find /path -printf "%f: %p: %u: %g %m (%M) \n"
```

check the man page of `find` more the meaning of those specifiers.

Answer (score 5):

You should actually do it that way

```
find /path -printf "%f:%p:%u:%g:%m\n"
```

That way you get also the permissions and each file gets listed on one line.

Answer (score 4):

```
ls | xargs stat --printf "$(pwd)/%n %U %G %A \n"
```

Comment: This seems to me to be the most direct way to accomplish the result